# How to click on webelement if id's of that particular element is changing with submission using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Id's of Webelement is changing then what is the best way to click on that element. I am working with selenium Webdriver latest.

Comment: Please read [How to ask on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I have autogenerated ids my self, i use the name of the specified element to find it and then click on it.

Since the name is also unique on each webpage in my case and i can not use the dynamical generated ids from the web elements.

Comment: That is not a valid answer. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.